# Ext JS 6.5 Menu auto-hide

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am using Ext JS 6.5.3.57 . I have file `Menu.js` for view

```
Ext.define('Foo.view.menu.Menu', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'menu_foo',

    requires: [
        'Ext.menu.Menu'
    ],

    autoSize: true,
    bodyPadding: 20,
    width: 230,
    items: {
        xtype: 'menu',
        floated: false,
        docked: 'left',
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        items: [{
            text: 'System setup',
        },{
            text: 'Cash'
        },{
            text: 'regular item 3'
        }]
    }

})
```

File `app.js`

```
// File /Users/donhuvy/Desktop/vy_sencha/app.js

/*
 * This file launches the application by asking Ext JS to create
 * and launch() the Application class.
 */
Ext.application({
    extend: 'Acc.Application',

    name: 'Foo',

    requires: [
        // This will automatically load all classes in the Foo namespace
        // so that application classes do not need to require each other.
        'Foo.*'
    ],

    // The name of the initial view to create.
    //mainView: 'Foo.view.main.Main'
    mainView: 'Foo.view.menu.Menu'

});
```

When I press on menu item, it hide automatically. How to avoid it hide after click on menu item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [hideOnClick](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.menu.Item.html#cfg-hideOnClick) config in `Ext.menu.Item` that is `true` by deafult

And [autoHide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/modern/Ext.menu.Menu.html#cfg-autoHide) config on `Ext.menu.Menu` that is `true` by default

If you set `hideOnClick` to `false` it won't hide it's owner menu

If you set `autoHide` to `false` it prevents the menu from auto-hiding when focus moves elsewhere

So just add following code to menu config

```
{
   allowOtherMenus: true,
   autoHide: false,
   defaults:{ 
       hideOnClick: false 
   }
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2hae)

Comment: Please show me how to set configuration? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Added to answer